# What are the Onpremise Open source endpoint monitoring tools?

Tags: monitoring, endpoints

We need an open source endpoint monitoring tool in the cloud. 
Main requirement checking websites and APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could not find a decent continuous monitoring solution other than https://www.nagios.org/

We are using the site24x7 to monitor our endpoints. ( it is better to use a third party for this )